# converting WPF project to Silverlight. Somehow the application crashes

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Im trying to convert my WPF project to Silverlight. The WPF project was written in MVVM template. it doesnt connect to any database, ive used an XML serializer to create and read from XML file.

But somehow the application crashes. I think it maybe the App.Xaml. But I am unable to debug the silverlight application, as it gives an error "The breakpoint will not currently be hit., no symbols have been loaded for this document"....

Not too sure where to go from here...

```
  private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {


            Views.MainPage view = new Views.MainPage();


            ViewModels.MainPageViewModel mainViewModel = new ViewModels.MainPageViewModel();


            mainViewModel.LoadProducts("Products.xml");


            view.DataContext = mainViewModel;

            this.RootVisual = view;

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried turniing on "stop on all exceptions?"  Do you get any error from the debugger at all?  Why do you think the App.xaml?

Comment: Ok, Now I have figured out what is wrong, there is something wrong with my load method, it calls a XML deserializer, it must be what is wrong. But I still cant figure out why I am unable to use the debugger...

Comment: Usually that message (about not hitting breakpoints) means you're either not running a debug build, or your debugging a copy of the app that doesn't match the code.  Are you sure you're rebuilding your whole solution before you start?

Comment: Hi, yap. I rebuilt the whole solution from the start. I manually ported the code. So I cant see why it would give that message. it was running in "Debug", not "Release"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the problem or not, but you mentioned that your WPF application read from an XML file.  Where is this XML file located?  Silverlight is going to have some limitations on what it can access if it is being run in-browser, and may not be able to read the file if the `LoadProducts` method tries to read it from disk.

Comment: oh... right.. thanks so much! That must be the reason, because my XML file is stored in a temporary file location,  String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(); !

Answer (score 0):

The App.xaml is loaded before your user-code executes, so that may be the problem with the breakpoint. Can't you attach to the process to see what the exception is?

Comment: Thanks. i will put up my App.Xaml.CS code. There is no exception, the webpage has nothing displayed, seems like it is waiting forever, and the breakpoints doesnt work. How can I attach to the process?

Comment: What system are you running this with? VS 2010 with Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio installed?

Comment: hi, Yap, I have Silverlight 4 toolkit for VS2010 installed.